# JSON Object no me funciona - Android

Tags: php, java, android, json

quiero recuperar unos datos mediante un API REST y solamente tengo problema que no ejecuta la sentencia de: `if(sucess.equals("2"))`
El JSON mediante la URL me muestra correctamente lo siguiente:

```
{"sucess":"2"}
```

No se porqué si supuestamente es un json object.

Esta es el código JAVA:

Este es el código Java:

```
public void mostrarDatos() {
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            arrayCuposLibres.clear();
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                String sucess=jsonObject.getString("sucess");
                JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("cuposlibres");
                if (sucess.equals("1")) {
                    for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++) {
                        JSONObject object= jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String id_cupolibre= object.getString("id_cupolibre");
                        String grupo_descripcion= object.getString("grupo_descripcion");
                        String nombres = object.getString("personas_nombre");
                        String apellido = object.getString("personas_apellido");
                        String cupolibre_total = object.getString("cupolibre_total");
                        String hora_inicio = object.getString("horarios_hora_inicio");
                        String hora_fin = object.getString("horarios_hora_fin");
                        String id_grupo = object.getString("grupo_id");
                        String fecha_reserva = object.getString("fecha");
                        cuposLibres = new CuposLibres(id_cupolibre, grupo_descripcion, nombres+" " + apellido,
                                cupolibre_total,"de "+hora_inicio+" a " +  hora_fin, id_grupo, fecha_reserva);
                        arrayCuposLibres.add(cuposLibres);
                        adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
                if(sucess.equals("2")) {
                    tvReservaRealizada.setText("funciona");
                    tvReservaRealizada.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
```

El código PHP:

```
<?php

include 'conexion.php';
$alumno_id= $_GET['alumno_id'];

$consulta = "select * from reservas where alumno_id = '$alumno_id'";
$resultado=$conexion-> query($consulta);
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

if ($num_rows > 0) {  
    $result = array();        
    $result["sucess"]="2";
    echo json_encode($result);
    mysqli_close($conexion);
}
else {
    $result = array();        
    $result['cuposlibres'] = array();        
    $select = "select cuposlibres.cupolibre_id, grupos.descripcion, personas.nombres, personas.apellido, cuposlibres.total, horarios.hora_inicio, horarios.hora_fin, grupos.grupo_id, cuposlibres.fecha from grupos inner join personas ON grupos.profesor_id = personas.personas_id INNER join cuposlibres on cuposlibres.grupo_id = grupos.grupo_id inner join horarios on horarios.horario_id = grupos.horario_id";
    
    $mostrar =mysqli_query($conexion,$select);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($mostrar)) {
        $index['id_cupolibre'] = $row['0'];
        $index['grupo_descripcion'] = $row['1'];
        $index['personas_nombre'] = $row['2'];
        $index['personas_apellido'] = $row['3'];
        $index['cupolibre_total'] = $row['4'];
        $index['horarios_hora_inicio'] = $row['5'];
        $index['horarios_hora_fin'] = $row['6'];
        $index['grupo_id'] = $row['7'];
        $index['fecha'] = $row['8'];        
    
        array_push($result['cuposlibres'],$index);
    }
    $result["sucess"]="1";
    echo json_encode($result);
    mysqli_close($conexion);
}
```

?>

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Despues de recuperar el sucess                 String sucess=jsonObject.getString("sucess");
haz un System.out para ver si de verdad es 2.

Answer (score 0):

Ya pude solucionar era porque el `JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("cuposlibres");`
tendría que estar dentro de la sentenci: `if (sucess.equals("1"))` porque al no encontrar resultado ahí iba al catch.

Gracias!

Comment: Más bien deberías normalizar tu respuesta desde el servidor. Un código que podría devolver un JSON Object por un lado o un Json Array por otro no es muy coherente y dificulta escribir el código para manejar la respuesta en el cliente (Android en este caso).

Comment: Gracias por el consejo, saludos!